# Blur all of the images, if one of the images clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 images on my page. I have assigned `eventListener` to check for a click, once a click has occurred on one of the images, everything else gets blurred (including the other two images).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
function showInfo() {
  const images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  const container = document.getElementsByClassName("container");

  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
      // images[i].style.
    })
  }
}

showInfo();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp). That means if you click on each of them, it must run the command. But don't forget that this method is only possible for more than one HTML tag. (You have 3 images).

After clicking on each element, you must write a [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop (modern ecmascript-edition) so you can choose all of the images and apply the blur.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

images.forEach(e => {

  // e here means each image, no matter which one is the purpose

  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (let i in images) {
      images[i].style.filter = 'blur(8px)';
      i++;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
img {
  margin-block: 10px
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
```